# ASP.NET MVC: Do GET requests on private web pages have to be nondestructive?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC it seems to be common practice not to use GET requests for calls to a controller that modify the model. For example, deleting a customer should not be possible by clicking a simple HTML link.

The only reason for this rule I am aware of is not safeguard against web-crawlers which might indavertently alter the database. GET requests are commonly regarded as safe, whereas POST requests are not.

Does this mean that this rule does not apply to non-public portions of a website (Example: Your password-protected user administration area)? Or is there any other reason not to use destructive GET requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally part of HTTP. From [the HTTP 1.1 RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1)

> Implementors should be aware that the
>   software represents the user in their
>   interactions over the Internet, and
>   should be careful to allow the user to
>   be aware of any actions they might
>   take which may have an unexpected
>   significance to themselves or others.
>
> In particular, the convention has been
>   established that the GET and HEAD
>   methods SHOULD NOT have the
>   significance of taking an action other
>   than retrieval. These methods ought to
>   be considered "safe". This allows user
>   agents to represent other methods,
>   such as POST, PUT and DELETE, in a
>   special way, so that the user is made
>   aware of the fact that a possibly
>   unsafe action is being requested.
>
> Naturally, it is not possible to
>   ensure that the server does not
>   generate side-effects as a result of
>   performing a GET request; in fact,
>   some dynamic resources consider that a
>   feature. The important distinction
>   here is that the user did not request
>   the side-effects, so therefore cannot
>   be held accountable for them.

In other words, it's not enforced, but it's really bad form for a GET request to have side-effects. Imagine if a user bookmarks a URL which does updates something, for example - they probably wouldn't expect that to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Another good reason is accelerator plug-ins for browsers. These attempt to speed up page loads by pre-fetching links on the current page. Imagine if you had a bunch of GET requests to delete all the objects in a list, the plug-in would delete them!

The short of it is that you can't predict what a browser will do with GET requests, if it looks like a plain-old hyperlink then its fair game for a browser to go fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

It's not just about web crawlers, it's about CRSF - Cross Site Request Forgery.

So imagine that someone is logged into your web site, and browses to www.hax0rs.com

In the source for hax0rs.com is the following tag

```
<img src="http://mysite.com/members/statusChange?status=I%20am%20looking%20for%20a%20gimp%20mask" height="0" width="0">
```

Because your user is logged in, and because the request is going to your site, the authentication cookie goes with it. And bang, suddenly your user's status has changed.

What fun :)

Comment: But he could do the same with a post requests as well. For example he could make me click on a harmless looking mislabeled button. Having a POST request does not really increase security in this case.

Comment: This is also possible with POST. Even without a click. Just a javascript that submits a form.

Comment: True, however it's easier to protect forms with a token or canary. Doing to a URL is ugly and breaks bookmarking.

Answer (score 0):

But I suppose you can still do some sort of "non-retrieval" actions on GET requests. For example updating the "LastVisit" records which can be consider undestructive and relatively safe.